# Bootstrap slider acting weird on Vercel but working on local server and StackBlitz

Tags: angular, deployment, slider, bootstrap-slider

I am trying to deploy an app I made with Angular (frontend) and PHP backend and I ran into a problem while deploying the frontend part to [Vercel](https://melogdiary.vercel.app/home). The Bootstrap slider is acting weird and I am not sure how to solve this.

I managed to make it work on StackBlitz:https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-j4wzbj?file=src%2Fslide%2Fslide%2Fslide.component.html
and it is working as expected.

In the application slider is getting the data from the database, but for the purposes of deploying frontend part to Vercel I made a JSON file with dummy data.

I would be really grateful for any help with this. I've been looking at this for hours now and I can not seem to find a solution :( Btw I am a beginner and this is my first deployment, so I would really appreciate any help.

The result should be like this (this is screenshot from the localserver)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tDxsB.gif)